# MongoError: Unknown modifier $pushAll when I try to push an userId into an Array field in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm getting a `MongoError: Unknown modifier $pushAl` error when I try to push an `userId` to an Array of likes field:

[image: MongoDB push error]

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are trying to use?

Comment: Fix it! Just added {usePushEach:true} in schema and becomes likes that new mongoose.Schema({props}, {usePushEach: true});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$pushAll`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/pushAll/) has been deprecated since version `2.4`:

> *Deprecated since version 2.4: Use the $push operator with $each instead.*

You can/should upgrade to a more recent version of Mongoose that is [compatible](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html) with the MongoDB version you are using or downgrade MongoDB to an older version that still supports `$pushAll`. I would advise the former.

Alternatively, you could use the `usePushEach: true` option when defining your schema, if you are using Mongoose version `< 5`:

```
new mongoose.Schema({ ... }, {
    usePushEach: true,
});
```

You can read more on that issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5574):

> **[vkarpov15](https://github.com/vkarpov15?tab=overview&from=2018-04-14) commented on 26 Sep 2017**
>
> Well that's one problem, MongoDB `3.5` is an unstable dev release and should not be used. `$pushAll` has been deprecated for a long time so perhaps they got rid of it in `3.5`. [@mbroadst](https://github.com/mbroadst) can you clarify?
>
> We added a `usePushEach` option to work around this a while back: [#4455](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4455), that should be a workaround for this issue:
>
> ```
> new Schema({ arr: [String] }, { usePushEach: true });
> ```

Support for `usePushEach` was dropped on [Mongoose version `>= 5`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#500-rc0--2017-12-28), so in that case, you could use [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead, so your old code:

```
selectedHotel.likes.push(userId);
```

Would turn into:

```
selectedHotel.likes = selectedHotel.likes.concat([userId]);
```

Note that I'm assigning the value returned by `concat` back to `selectedHotel.likes`, as `concat` does not mutate the original Array.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
selectedHotel._doc.likes.push({//anything})
```

or 
this 
My old code,

```
myArray.push(id); //breaks on DocumentDB with Mongo API because of $pushAll
```

has been replaced with,

```
myArray = myArray.concat([id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue simply by updating to the latest version of mongoose. I was having the same issue while using version 4.6, I did `npm uninstall mongoose`, then `npm i mongoose` which installed version 5.11.18, the latest one at the moment of writing this, and the issue got solved.
This for me was a very simple solution without having to change anything in my code and it adds up to what was said above.